# Selection Sort trouble with indexes

Tags: c#, algorithm, indexing

Actually I'm dealing with CodeAbbey problem, so I don't want answer as code, but explenation about that, what I am doing wrong. http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/selection-sort

My Selection Sort actually works without any problems, but I don't know why I do not get proper indexes (when sorting works!). I.e. for input data:`5 1 3 6 2 4 7 9 8 0` I got it sorted to `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`, as I wished.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SelectionSort
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        int howMany = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //length of array
        List<int> Base = new List<int>(Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(), int.Parse)); //input to array (i.e. 5 1 3 6 2 4 7 9 8 0 => { 5, 1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 7, 9, 8, 0 })
        List<int> Output = new List<int>(); // list to store sorted array

        string[] ans = new string[howMany];   // array for storing answers

        int loops = Base.Count();

        for(int i = 0; i != loops; i++)
        {
            int topID = 0, topValue = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j != Base.Count(); j++)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    topID = 0;
                    topValue = Base[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    if(topValue < Base[j])
                    {
                        topValue = Base[j];
                        topID = j;   
                    }
                }
            }
            ans[i] = topID.ToString();  //after looping through array save topID to answer array
            Output.Add(Base[topID]);    //add topValue to output
            Base.RemoveAt(topID);       //remove topValue with index topID from list
        }

        //Output.Reverse();                 // Writing on stdout
        //foreach(var s in Output)          // sorted array
        //{                                 //
        //    Console.Write(s + " ");       // It works without any problems
        //}                                 //
        //Console.ReadLine();               //

        foreach(var s in ans)
        {
            Console.Write(s + " ");    // write on stdout stored indexes
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

  }
}
```

I.e. for such a test data:

`124
144 146 4 121 106 142 153 168 122 42 135 127 126 16 193 52 29 161 186 83 152 72 51 125 37 116 187 133 183 132 80 53 185 129 7 189 98 128 32 33 56 157 49 50 10 77 11 196 160 162 68 43 14 181 112 113 94 100 165 79 172 159 156 57 9 6 66 86 17 63 46 178 130 88 192 124 105 182 34 18 76 155 24 89 123 12 179 109 188 13 40 5 163 45 27 85 103 93 69 58 25 81 145 92 30 138 154 177 158 140 91 171 139 67 175 184 120 8 54 147 84 174 95 55`

I got it sorted to:
`4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 16 17 18 24 25 27 29 30 32 33 34 37 40 42 43 45 46 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 63 66 67 68 69 72 76 77 79 80 81 83 84 85 86 88 89 91 92 93 94 95 98 100 103 105 106 109 112 113 116 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 132 133 135 138 139 140 142 144 145 146 147 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 165 168 171 172 174 175 177 178 179 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 192 193 196`

and I got such an indexes:
`47 14 72 34 84 25 17 29 107 25 69 46 76 63 94 100 105 52 96 7 49 76 41 15 39 47 86 33 46 61 82 6 15 87 1 75 0 3 76 77 75 5 16 16 46 18 20 5 5 11 42 48 3 1 64 10 26 25 44 1 36 48 25 12 58 23 45 49 50 37 32 28 41 49 5 43 8 21 16 29 5 35 16 37 21 22 32 18 11 34 33 7 3 4 9 8 15 22 10 1 18 3 12 5 4 17 2 14 14 10 9 8 1 4 7 6 3 2 2 4 1 1 1 0`

when I was supposed to get these:
`47 14 74 35 88 26 18 32 115 28 77 53 86 71 107 28 74 60 86 7 58 92 49 17 48 61 28 41 62 81 60 6 20 88 1 6 0 5 74 53 5 10 27 29 72 33 37 11 12 23 12 53 8 3 32 25 55 54 0 4 11 41 57 36 14 56 28 56 8 5 12 8 41 35 19 19 30 14 45 29 21 28 35 37 5 32 19 11 19 30 26 31 15 22 21 28 3 11 19 9 6 9 11 5 15 7 16 3 3 10 12 3 3 8 1 6 6 3 4 3 1 0 1`

What am I doing wrong?
Greetings

Comment: Your code might benefit from Code Review SE once the bug has been fixed. There are a ton of stylistic problems that you might want to understand and avoid in the future.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a very short array, e.g. length 3?

Comment: Actually it works without any problems with such a short arrays

Comment: I doubt that. The bug surely does not require a 100 item array. There is nothing in the code that would trigger a new code path only with very long arrays. I suggest you test the code with all possible permutations of `1,2,3,4`. The bug *will* be found that way, I bet money on it.

Comment: How do you know that the indexes are incorrect actually? They might be correct and your alleged solution might be wrong.

Comment: When I put my result to "tester" it gives me result: "Wrong answer: Expected was: " and listed indexes.

Comment: And some of mine are good but some of them just don't much (compare indexes I got and indexes I was supposed to get)

Comment: Why are there duplicate indexes? That should not be possible. `... 1 0 1` is completely wrong. Don't you agree?

Comment: Duplicates are possible, cause we are removing biggest values (i.e. if we have `2 3 1` then it output should be `1 0 0`, but last index should be 0, I'll think a bit about it. Thanks!

Comment: You already have a way of finding the bug: test the code with all possible permutations of 1,2,3,4. Realize that you can solve this problem yourself. If you want to learn how to program well you need to develop tools to solve problems yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly, you are not following the expected algorithm, hence the difference.

The expectation is to **exchange** the found max element on each step with the current last element, and you have implemented it differently by **removing** the found max element. While this produces correct sorted output, the indices are different (`RemoveAt` relocates all indices after the one being removed).

To get the expected results, implement the algorithm exactly as described in the problem description.

Or correct the above implementations as follows:

Replace

```
for(int j = 0; j != Base.Count(); j++)
```

with

```
int lastID = Base.Count - 1 - i;
for (int j = 0; j <= lastID; j++)
```

then replace

```
Base.RemoveAt(topID);
```

with

```
Base[topID] = Base[lastID];
Base[lastID] = topValue;
```

and you are done.

Also note that this is **inplace** algorithm, and at the end `Base` list will contain the sorted result, so the `Output` list is redundant.